# Count Number Of Changes Per Group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Given this data:

| Project Manager | Project Num | Employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 1 |
| A | 4 | 1 |
| B | 5 | 1 |
| B | 6 | 1 |
| A | 7 | 1 |
| A | 8 | 1 |
| B | 9 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 2 |
| A | 4 | 2 |
| A | 5 | 2 |
| B | 6 | 2 |
| A | 7 | 2 |

I want This Result :

| Manager_Change_Counter | Employee |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

I need to count per employee how many project manger changes made regardless of number of projects

Comment: Please edit your question, and share your simple data as text instead of images, so it can be easy for us to help you

Comment: Also, T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using the window function `lag()` to retrieve the previous row and determine whether or not *Project Manager* has been changed, then calculating the total time of changes :

```
WITH CTE AS (
  select Employee,
       Project_Manager,
       lag(Project_Manager, 1, Project_Manager) over (partition by Employee order by Project_Num) as PREV_Project_Manager
  from mytable
)
SELECT Employee, SUM(case when Project_Manager = PREV_Project_Manager then 0 else 1 end) as Manager_Change_Counter
from CTE
GROUP BY Employee
```

Result :

```
Employee    Manager_Change_Counter
1           5
2           4
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/B94lFW3m)